# Scale the size of CALayer contents

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, calayer

I have a few UIImageViews inside CALayer. How do I scale them all at once? I did try setting CALayer properties like `la.contentsGravity = @"kCAGravityResizeAspect";` but the images inside the layer always display the original size.

Answer (score 70):

if `layer` contains the image, this will scale it to 65%

```
layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(.65, .65, 1);
```

Comment: Why does that do nothing to mine when it leave the third number 1 and start working when I also set that .65 just like the first and the second?

Comment: @durazno: applying a 3-dimensional transform on a 2-dimensional structure — the third parameter (z) is irrelevant. if you would rotate around the z-axis prior to this code, using another value than 1 should result in different results.

Comment: This worked bot only **after** I added the layer as a sublayer. Eg. `view.layer.addSublayer(myLayer)`; `myLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.65, 0.65, 1)`

Comment: @LanceSamaria hence the first sentence "if layer contains the image"

Comment: @vikingosegundo hi, thanks for replying. **Your answer 100% works, I even upvoted it**. But when I added the image to the layer first, did the transform second, then added the layer to the view's layer third, the transform didn't occur. It only worked for me in this order: add the image to the layer first, add the layer to the view's layer second, and transform third. Again, you answer definitely works, but adding the image to the layer first and doing the transform before adding the layer to the view didn't work for me.

Comment: why would you expect that to work? it doesn't make any sense.